# What is the difference between AP A and AP B?

Tags: united-states

I am a British person, currently studying a book designed for the American market.

It is for students studying the AP B course.

I know that AP stands for Advanced Placement, which is similar to the UK A-Level courses we study at 17-18 years of age.

However, I do not know what the difference is between the A and B part. For example, AP Physics A in comparison to AP Physics B?

Comment: It's roughly the difference between "Mathematics" and "Further Mathematics".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AP courses are designed for US high school students to gain some transfer credits when they begin university study by passing a standardized exam with a sufficient score, effectively giving a jump on their first year.

There's no such thing as "AP A" and "AP B" except in the context of particular courses. Some subjects may have multiple parts, but they aren't named in any cohesive fashion across subjects.

I suggest going directly to the College Board for info on what the AP courses cover, but from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AP_Physics) it seems that both AP Physics A and B are defunct, with AP Physics A never fully existing.

You can see a full course list here: https://apstudents.collegeboard.org/course-index-page

Looks like AP Physics 1 is Newtonian mechanics, AP Physics 2 is electricity and magnetism.  They have a separate track AP Physics C: Mechanics and AP Physics C: Electricity and Magnetism which use calculus. Of course different universities are different, but probably 1&2 are roughly equivalent to 2 semesters of a US university "not for majors" physics track, and the two AP Physics C branches are roughly equivalent to 2 semesters of a US university "for majors" track (including majors in engineering, physics, possibly biology and other science/quantitative areas). Whether a university actually would accept even high scores on these AP tests as equivalents to their own courses is up to the individual schools.

Comment: And yes, this varies widely by discipline. Some universities give credit for high scores on the associated standardized exams, but I doubt that many give credit for the courses themselves absent those high scores.

Comment: @Buffy Thanks, I clarified to make clear that it's the test scores rather than completion of the courses that gives credit.

Comment: I heard US students are told not to take an AP class unless they are certain they will get an A in it, otherwise it is extra work for nothing.

Comment: @questioner, the trend for a few years now in many schools has been to encourage students to take AP courses, even if they reasonably anticipate not receiving an A.  The Challenge Index rates high schools based on number of AP courses taken, not passed.  This is viewed in some circles as one way to decrease achievement gaps, and to introduce students to the rigors of college coursework.

Comment: @lamplamp Makes sense when the rest of the world does the UK equivalent of A-Levels at 17 and 18 years old, which are basically AP courses.